# If I update a column record in a table, will indexes that do NOT have this column in it be affected?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, index, nonclustered-index

In terms of performance if I have a table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [TESTDATA].[TableA](
    [Col1] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Col2] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [Col3] [float] NULL
CONSTRAINT [TableA_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Col1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

And then create a non-clustered index like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_idx_TableA]
ON [TESTDATA].[TableA] ([Col2])
WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

If I perform an update to the table, only changing `Col3` does the DB need to touch the index `_idx_TableA`?

Just curious how far performance touches all indexes?

Comment: Bear in mind that both the below answers are correct, but updates on the underlying tables can force statistics updates on the indexes as well.  This is probably less costly than updating the data in the index itself but it still is a cost to consider.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `_idx_TableA` will not be affected for this operation.  I have modified your example and added another index (NCI) that actually includes the key column `Col3`.  Here's my example code:

```
use testdb;
go

CREATE TABLE [DBO].[TableA](
    [Col1] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [Col2] [nchar](2) NULL,
    [Col3] [int] NULL
CONSTRAINT [TableA_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Col1] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_idx_TableA]
ON [DBO].[TableA] ([Col2])
WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

create nonclustered index IX_Col3
on dbo.TableA(Col3);
go

insert into dbo.TableA
values
    ('a', 'b', 10),
    ('b', 'c', 11),
    ('c', 'd', 12);
go

update dbo.TableA
set Col3 = 13;
```

If I capture the post execution plan of the `UPDATE` command, you will see something similar here:

[image]

As you see from the above screenshot, the indexes that are updated are the clustered index, and my nonclustered index `IX_Col3`.  **The index `_idx_TableA` does not get updated**.  Therefore, only the indexes that contain `Col3` will be affected, and therefore updated by your particular example.

Comment: Thanks, how can I find that execution plan myself? That seems extremely handy.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Initially you ask the question on my post, I edited the post.

Answer (score 3):

No. Since the update does not update data in neither **col 2** nor the **clustered key (col 1)**, the index _idx_TableA with only col 2 does not get updated.

@professionalAmateur, click on the execution plan button on the top.

[image]

Run you query. Execution plan tab should show as below.

[image]